# Auth provider is showing in "Included by" tab as "Refresh to view"

Tags: managed-package, package-install

While **making** a package, my Auth Provider is showing value as "**Refresh to view**" in "Included by" tab .

On refreshing also its not changing. Thus on **installing** the package to another org, the auth provider isn't visible in the component list.

Hence causing insufficient privileges error while opening external data source from the package's component list (as nothing available inside external data source if opened from quick search so for checking purpose I am opening it from installed package component list)

Can anyone tell me what could be the problem?

Comment: What kind of package are you creating? Auth Provider is only packageable in an unlocked 2GP or in a Change Set. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/metadata-coverage/48

Comment: I am creating managed-released package and cannot use unmanaged or change set.

Answer (score 0):

Finally we have solved this by giving **Files Connect Cloud** system permission.